# angular change detection for updates within a callback

Tags: angular, typescript

I am looking for reasoning about a simple problem.
I have a simple component which has a boolean property which i display in the component's template.Now the problem is that if I update this property in a callback, the property does get updated (in the component) but the updated value does not get rendered (change detection does not work, and I have to explicitly call `changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();` to render the updated value).

I have this in my template:

```
<div *ngIf="isUserLoggedIn">
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
<div *ngIf="!isUserLoggedIn">
    <div id="googleBtn" (click)="onSignIn()">Sign In</div>
</div>
```

and this in my component:

```
gapi.load('auth2', () => {
      this.auth2 = gapi.auth2.init({
        client_id: '769107420471-782b0i2f3dt9u05dhrb4j21g7ajglrg6.apps.googleusercontent.com',
        cookiepolicy: 'single_host_origin',
        scope: 'profile email'
      });
      var googleBtn = document.getElementById('googleBtn');
      if(googleBtn) {
        this.attachSignin(document.getElementById('googleBtn'));
      }
    });
  }
  public attachSignin(element) {
    this.auth2.attachClickHandler(element, {},
      (googleUser) => {
        this.signUpService.googleLogin(googleUser.getAuthResponse().id_token, 
        this.successCallback.bind(this), 
        this.signOut.bind(this));
      }, (error) => {
        alert(JSON.stringify(error, undefined, 2));
      });
  }

  successCallback = function (data) {
    // this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
    this.isUserLoggedIn = this.utils.isUserLoggedIn();
  }
```

as you can see the expected behaviour is : initially "isUserLoggedIn" will be false, and then user clicks on "Sign In" button, which calls a function from another service and toggles "isUserLoggedIn" in the successCallback of that function thus resulting in the template elements also getting toggled.

But this only happens if I uncomment the first line in successCallback (),
my quest is why do I need to explicitly call `changeDetectorRef.detectChanges()` to reflect changes in dom, why change detection is not working with callback (I checked other wise, with simple `Observable.interval(2000).subscribe(x => {this.isUserLoggedIn = !this.isUserLoggedIn});` which works perfectly fine)

Comment: Can you provide what you have so far?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It doesn't work because `load` event callback is triggered outside of Angular zone. You can fix it like this:

```
constructor(private zone: NgZone) {}

gapi.load('auth2', () => {
    zone.run(() => {
        this.auth2 = gapi.auth2.init({
            client_id: '769107420471-glrg6.apps.googleusercontent.com',
            cookiepolicy: 'single_host_origin',
            scope: 'profile email'
        });
        var googleBtn = document.getElementById('googleBtn');
```

For more information read:

- [Do you still think that NgZone (zone.js) is required for change detection in Angular?](https://blog.angularindepth.com/do-you-still-think-that-ngzone-zone-js-is-required-for-change-detection-in-angular-16f7a575afef#f618)

Comment: thanks for your response @AngularInDepth.com it helped to fix.. :), so the reason my callback runs outside ng zone is that i am using auth2.attachClickHandler("elementId") to explicitly attach the handler for the click event, which forbids angular from patching the handler with change detection details.. am I right? and good job with https://blog.angularindepth.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-change-detection-in-angular-8006c51d206f Its been amazing to read your articles..

Comment: you're welcome, thanks for the feedback.  the callback is not executed in the angular zone because `gapi` is executing its async tasks outside angular zone. I'm writing an article on zones now and will explain this behavior there. stay tuned! :)

Comment: awesome.. eager for the new article.. :)

Comment: @FreakAtNs, just published the relevant article. See [Do you still think that NgZone (zone.js) is required for change detection in Angular?](https://blog.angularindepth.com/do-you-still-think-that-ngzone-zone-js-is-required-for-change-detection-in-angular-16f7a575afef)

Comment: @AngularInDepth.com do you think running `cdr.detectChanges` would be better performance-wise since it triggers change detection only in the parent and child components and `zone.run` triggers the whole zone? great article btw :-) (clap)

Comment: @echonax, using `zone.run()` is preferable because all async operations scheduled inside the `zone.run()` callback will be later picked up by `NgZone` whereas with `cd.detectChanges` you will have to trigger CD manually for each async operation. Thanks for the clap)

Comment: @AngularInDepth.com maybe I'm misunderstanding something here; if we trigger cd manually inside the `gapi.load` callback, wouldn't the value be updated ? Just like your first example in the article (https://blog.angularindepth.com/do-you-still-think-that-ngzone-zone-js-is-required-for-change-detection-in-angular-16f7a575afef#e7b4).

Comment: @echonax, it will be, but if you use `setTimeout()` inside the callback and update the property you will not see the update in DOM. You will have to trigger cd manually again

Comment: @AngularInDepth.com yes and if I trigger cd manually with `detectChanges` inside `gapi.load` it would trigger a smaller "zone" than `zone.run()` don't you think? So It will be more efficient I guess?

Comment: @echonax, there's no "smaller zone" :). If you mean it will run CD for smaller subset of components, yes, that's correct. But then you can disable `NgZone` and run all checks manually. That would be very efficient, but how convenient? That's the answer to you question I guess

Comment: @AngularInDepth.com yes I agree that convenience would be an issue :-) thanks for clearing up the questions in my mind :-)

Comment: @echonax, glad I could help! :)