# Angular doesn't update UI with new value (only if explicitly forced to)

Tags: angular, angular2-changedetection

I recently learned about the possibility to access the sensors of a device through the browser with js (currently only really works with Chromium browsers on mobile devices and a requires a https connection on top).
My goal was to display the readings of a sensor (e.g. Accelerometer) provided by its [`onreading`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Sensor/onreading) EventHandler in a simple angular application.

*Minimal example:*

app.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
 selector: 'my-app',
 templateUrl: './app.component.html',
 styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})

export class AppComponent implements OnInit{
 sensor;
 reading = 0;

 ngOnInit() {
  const sensorFunction = window['Accelerometer'];
  this.sensor = new sensorFunction({ frequency: 1 });
  this.sensor.start();

  this.sensor.onreading = (ev) => {
   this.reading = ev.currentTarget.x;
   console.log(this.reading);
  };
 }
}
```

app.component.html

```
<p> Reading is {{ reading }}</p>
```

I also created a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-53my8u?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) with the same code.

---

Since the UI wouldn't update and show the current value of `reading`, I found 2 solutions to force an update:

1. Add empty `setInterval`
2. Use `ChangeDetectorRef` and call `detectChanges()` everytime there is a new reading from the sensor

They both fix the problem and update the UI to show the new value, but I'm curious why angular didn't detect the change automatically.
What am I missing here?
Does it have something to do with using an EventHandler to set the value?
*(I also tried passing the sensor readings as an input value to a child component or using a different lifecycle hook, but got the same result*)

Comment: My guess is that zone.js doesn't pach the sensor event handling.

Comment: Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46286400/2050306

Comment: Yep, it was indeed outside the Angular zone. Thanks a lot @JBNizet and @robert!